# Is there a way to search for less than and greater than numeric values on a page's content with Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions

Can Google Chrome (or any other browser for that matter) be coaxed into searching for `<` or `>` values on page content? I frequently find myself attempting to search for content that has numeric content and need to find values that are larger or smaller than a certain value. Thus far I've never found such a solution for a web browser to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that [Brian Z's previous answer](https://superuser.com/a/1579458/103907) is no longer "alive" and there might be other options available such as:

- [find+ | Regex Find-in-Page Tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/find%20-regex-find-in-page/fddffkdncgkkdjobemgbpojjeffmmofb)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it, but it looks like [the Chrome extension called Number Search](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/number-search/mknlabdjmmionkakcobggbihpiaelbnk?hl=en) will do exactly what you are asking for.

Comment: Extension gone - dead now. Any new ones?

Answer (score 0):

I tried Number Search initially, but it wouldn't do anything when I clicked on it. The guy who made the program seems very sincere in his response to user feedback, so think one of Chrome's update may have caused issues.

Regardless, that made me discover "Find+" extension for Chrome.
It took me a bit to figure out how to use the program to find digits, for instance I wanted to find all $ mentions between 100 and 999. The method was as follow:

The program can be easily opened by pressing Ctrl + Shift + F, as opposed to the normal Ctrl + F, still available.

Make sure "Find my Regular Expression" and "Match Case" is enabled in the Find+ settings.
Then search for $\d\d\d which will return any 3 digit (100-999) with $ in front. The reason for stipulating the dollar is cause there is often lots of other 3 digit strings such as time and dates and just stuff you don't want. So this worked for me.

Also, let's say I want to find any mention of '2 days', '3 days', etc. the search string was for instance: .2 d     or .3 d
This returned any string that followed the period.

The general rules for how to use these strings can be found here:
Syntax for Regular Expressions
https://support.google.com/a/answer/1371415?hl=en

Hope it's helpful! Let us find :)